# Стилизация плагина `select2`

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, плагин

Есть такой плагин `select2`. Хочу стилизовать его примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но тут есть проблемы, когда я абсолютным позиционированием вывожу выбранные опции, то и `input` выводится наружу.

Можете подсказать каким путем мне идти, чтобы добиться такого результата как на картинке.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.__select2').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an Industry',
        allowClear: false,
        tags: true,
        maximumSelectionLength: 5
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="__select2" multiple="multiple">
  <option>OAO & PHP</option>
  <option>OAO & MySQL</option>
  <option>OAO & Apache</option>
  <option>OAO & Java</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Bald Контейнер в опциях задается? или как?

Comment: @Bald Да я это понял, но это не дефолтный контейнер верно?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не красиво, но задачу выполняет.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.__select2').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an Industry',
        allowClear: false,
        tags: true,
        maximumSelectionLength: 5
    });
});
```

```css
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
    float: none !important;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
    position: absolute;
    right: -8px;
    top: -14px;
}

.select2-container .select2-search--inline {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    transform: translateY(-100%); /*тут через calc можно подровнять или через margin*/
    width: 90% !important;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field{
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="__select2" multiple="multiple">
  <option>OAO & PHP</option>
  <option>OAO & MySQL</option>
  <option>OAO & Apache</option>
  <option>OAO & Java</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ну в принципе главное выполнено. Сейчас посмотрю, спасибо.